# Error on Geoloqi website when loading p12 certificate

Tags: apple-push-notifications, pkcs#12

I am attempting to configure Apple push notifications for my Geoloqi app on the Geoloqi website by uploading p12 development and live certificates.  Unfortunately, when I click 'update' the website keeps informing me that 'There was a problem editing your application. Please check below.'  It also however 'hides' the Configure Apple push notifications area.  This means that no error message is displayed.  I know the P12 certificate for my app works as I've used it for Urban Airship with no problems.  I have also attempted this process on Safari, Chrome and Internet Explorer, hoping that the website might offer an error message for at least one of these browsers.
Any help offered with this situation would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the the issue where the error message is not appearing on the site this morning. Thanks for you patience with that.

Have you tried reexporting the p12 certificate from Keychain? (https://developers.geoloqi.com/ios/push-notifications) I would try that as a next step. I've sent an email to our CTO hopefully you should hear from soon.

Thanks for your patience,

Patrick Arlt
Geoloqi

Answer (score 1):

please try uploading the certificate again. We just added the password field so if you exported the certificate with a password, you'll have to enter it there. If that still doesn't work, please get in touch with us at support@geoloqi.com.